# Use of undeclared identifier ' ' in XCode 4.2

Tags: macos, xcode4.2, osx-mountain-lion

```
void CityXMLManager::print_patch_to_xml (
     patch_type _type, 
     vector <patch_type> & _neighbours_types, 
     vector <pair<Vector3, float > > & _obstacles)
```

Hi, 
I would like to ask if the lines above are accepted in terms of syntax? This line of code worked fine previously in Window and Visual Studio 2008 compilation. Then the errors come when the same code is threw into the mac os x environment. Some one passed down these codes to me and I do not understand what is happening in this line.

The errors complained are:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'patch_type'
Variable has incomplete type 'void'
'_neighbours_types' was not declared in this scope
'_patch_types' was not declared in this scope
Reference to 'vector' is ambiguous
```

Thanks in advance!